# Конструкцию "также как" нужно выделить запятыми или нет?

Tags: пунктуация

*Первичное действие дуги, также как резистивный нагрев, дополняется опасностью разлета нагретых частей.*

Я понимаю, что нужно обособить данную конструкцию, но каким именно образом? Или ее вообще не надо обособлять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё с запятыми правильно. Только *"так же как и"* пишется раздельно (лучше добавить И):

> Первичное действие дуги, так же как и резистивный нагрев, дополняется опасностью разлета нагретых частей.

Если интонационно выделяется ***так***, то обособляют оборот с *"как",* а перед *"так же"* запятую не ставят.